# Why am I not able to web scrape my facebook home page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape my facebook homepage which always is logged into on my machine using python and beautifulsoup. I am using the code below :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlo
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
url = 'https://www.facebook.com'
uclient = urlo(url)
page = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page,'html.parser')
x = page_soup.findAll('div',{'id':'fbNotificationsJewel'})
```

But x is returning an empty list. I want to work on the division showing number of notifications on facebook and return the number of notifications i have on my account. My account is always logged in ! Am I doing anything wrong or beuatiful soup can't do it. I am attaching a screenshot to show the element in html code to show what I am referring to :

[image]

Comment: Your facebook is pretty dynamic, so you can use `selenium` to render the page

Comment: Short answer: Facebook does not like to be scrapped and has several measures in place to make it complicated. Use their APIs.

Comment: Your browser is logged in, not your machine. The information stored in your browser that lets Facebook.com know who you are, is not shared with Python, that'd be a bit of a security problem. You need to write code to actually log into Facebook. This is not that trivial, and Facebook would much rather you use their [dedicated URLs for automated access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/).

Answer (score 0):

When you request a Facebook page but *haven't authenticated* then you will be presented with the standard login page.

I imagine that this element doesn't exist on that page and therefore returns nothing.

You need to look at authentication using beautiful soup. I can't give you an example unfortunately, but the answer is here in my post.